# Does LDAP take care of all users and groups on a system?

Tags: group, ldap

I have been following the [tutorial here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-client-computers-using-ldap-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) to try out LDAP. I know that a Linux system has groups like mysql, sudo, video, dial-out etc. Do I need to add these to my directory? Are these served via LDAP too?

What groups or users should or should not be in a directory?

Answer (score 1):

As they are already in the local `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` file and assuming you don't want do manage them globally which is normally the case with such technical accounts, there is no reason to add them to the directory server.

Moreover, as the `files` token is generally before the `ldap` one in the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` configuration file, the local settings would prevail anyway.

Note: beware that the link you posted is setting `ldap` before `compat` (equivalent to `files`) in `nsswitch.conf` which is quite unwise.

Comment: How does sudo command work in LDAP? is there a global root too? For something like `sudo su`? I am worried that the computer may be unusable if it looses network connectivity.

Comment: Your comment looks like a different, only loosely related question. You might want to ask it as a new one.